error in table of figures and wrong character
Since two weeks I switched from pdflatex to xetex. In doing so, I encounter two problems:
(1) an error message :
Undefined control sequence. ...exthebrew{בֵּיצָה}, \textit{b=e\d s=a}}
(2) In the list of figures, the Alif  is shown as an Ayn
How can I fix these?
A MWE:
% !TeX spellcheck = nl_NL
%!TeX program = xelatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=15mm,top=25mm,textwidth=180mm,textheight=249.7mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{dutch}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=hyphen, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Serif} 
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont[Color={0019D4}]{Courier New} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL Hebrew}%\texthebrew
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Script=Greek]{Liberation Serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\newfontfamily{\sblgr}[Script=Greek]{SBL Greek}
\newfontfamily{\greekfontsf}[Mapping=asciitogreek]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily{\greekfonttt}[Mapping=asciitogreek]{FreeMono}
\newcommand\testletter[1]{\rotatebox{180}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ayn}{\hspace{-.2mm}\raisebox{1.5mm}{\textnormal{\tiny c{}}}\hspace{-.1mm}}
\newcommand{\Alif}{\hspace{-1.2mm}\raisebox{1.5mm}{ \reflectbox{\textnormal{\tiny c{}}}}\hspace{-.1mm}}
\newcommand{\gk}[1]{\textgreek{\tb{#1}}}
\newcommand{\e}{ə} %segol
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\begin{small}
    \listoffigures
\end{small}
\linespread{1.0}


\section{languages}
\textgreek{ὅσοι δὲ ἔλαβον}

\texthebrew{יִרְאַ֣ת יְ֖הוָה רֵאשִׁ֣ית דָּ֑עַת חָכְמָ֥ה:}

\section{H0001 -- vader, \texthebrew{אָב}}
\label{H0001}

\<'Ab> \textit{\Alif{}\=a\b b} ...

\texthebrew{בֵּיצָה}, \textit{b\=e\d s\=a}

\begin{figure}[b]   
        
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\caption{H0001, \texthebrew{אָב}, \textit{\Alif{}\=a\b b} \texthebrew{בֵּיצָה}, \textit{b\=e\d s\=a}}

    
\end{figure}

\end{document}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} never do either of these with xetex. the first one will break the language support and the second one does nothing other than make a warning that it should not be used

A very personal suggestion: except if you need a xetex feature, switch to luatex instead.

Well, I skipped the two usepackages, unfortunately without success.
Tried with `\luatex', much better, but all the accents (dots and upper/lowerbars) in the list of figures don't appear.

Switching to LuaTex and set a new mainfont `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Charis SIL}' solves everything! Thanks David and Javier.

Do not use
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

which forces 8-bit legacy tex font encodings.
If you use luatex or xetex you should be able to directly access a suitable opentype font such as
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

(You don't need [Ligatures=TeX] as that is the default)
